# tableview with different section and row number

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As I'm new to swift I decided to check the problem with you guys to see what am I doing wrong?

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    for eachmain in data! {
        header.append(eachmain.unitPlaque!)
    }   
    return header[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {       
    if let data  = data { return Pphone.count }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    } else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell

    cell?.PhonNumberLbl.text = Pphone[indexPath.row]
    cell?.NameLbl.text = Nname[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

The code above shows the way I'm populating the table view. but each section might have a different number of rows. but here I get the same number of rows for each section!

even I tried the code below but it says that  character cannot be converted to a string

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell

    cell?.PhonNumberLbl.text = Pphone[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell?.NameLbl.text = Nname[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]    

    return cell!
}
```

**Api Response :**

```
    [ 
    {
    "contacts" : [
      {
        "id" : 10155,
        "selected" : true,
        "name" : "ygfb",
        "phoneNumber" : "09123809556"
      },
      {
        "id" : 10159,
        "selected" : true,
        "name" : "hff",
        "phoneNumber" : "08523698522"
      },
      {
        "id" : 9827,
        "selected" : true,
        "name" : "owner",
        "phoneNumber" : "09203137799"
      }
    ],
    "unitNo" : 1,
    "unitPlaque" : "jack",
    "billText" : "textetx"
  },
  {
    "contacts" : [
      {
        "id" : 10145,
        "selected" : true,
        "name" : "mmm",
        "phoneNumber" : "0912380567"
      }
    ],
    "unitNo" : 2,
    "unitPlaque" : "mm",
    "billText" : "textext"
  }
]
```

**Modal class:**

```
typealias smsModelList = [SmsModel]

struct SmsModel: Codable {
    var unitNo:Int?
    var unitPlaque:String?
    var billText:String?
    var contacts:[ContactsModel?]
}

typealias contactlistmodel = [ContactsModel]

struct ContactsModel: Codable {
    var id :Int?
    var selected :Bool?
    var phoneNumber : String?
    var name : String?
}
```

Comment: As per your code you should get for each section (count = data.count) you should get pphone.count numberOfRows. Can you show whats in your data and pphone.

Comment: in numberOfRowsInSection method you are returning Pphone.count which is same for all the sections !!

Comment: I just added the Api response as you wanted

Comment: you should get the count of data for the desired section(like for section 1 it is 3 contacts and for section 2 it is 1 contact only) instead of setting constant  "Pphone.count"  for every section.

Comment: @AmirFT How you want to populate the API response in the table view?. What is this data and Pphone ?? You are getting same rows because you are always returning Pphone.count

Comment: @Anuraj the unitPlaque will be the section header and name and phone number should be the rows under that section

Comment: Show us your modal class as well

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal updated , pls check

Comment: Ok thanks, try with my solution, I am supposing your `data` is `smsModelList`. And let me know what issues do you face.

Comment: @AmirFT So you have 2 sections right ? And contants.count number of rows in each section ?

Comment: @AmirFT First read the `UITableView` internal architecture and try to understand that how the section and a row works. Sections are not so different than rows or simple cells. You can implement multiple sections of `UITableView` just like how you implement cells by separating data models for Sections and its rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing `data` as `[SmsModel]?`. Below solution will work:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return data?[section].unitPlaque ?? ""
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {       
    return data?[section].contacts?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as! SmsTableViewCell

    cell.PhonNumberLbl.text = data?[indexPath.section].contacts?[indexPath.row].name
    cell.NameLbl.text = data?[indexPath.section].contacts?[indexPath.row].phoneNumber    

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Happy to help @AmirFT :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same number of rows in all sections because you are using same data in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let data  = data
    {
        return Pphone.count
    }
return 0
}
```

where you can use if.. else for different section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if section == 1 {
    return Pphone.count 
  } else if section == 2 {
  return 0
}
}
```

Comment: if let contactsArray = data[section] { 
     return contactsArray.contacts.count
 } else {
    return 0
 }}

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the count of `contact` for the number of rows. I am hoping data is the array of your whole content getting from the API. And the each object of the content you are storing in `eachmain`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if let dataAtSection = data[section] { // you are using eachmain for this i think , use something like dataAtSection = data[section] as eachmain()
     return dataAtSection.contacts.count
 } 
    return 0
 }
```

Comment: I understand that I have to count the number of conatacs for each sectvion but i don't understand the code

Comment: @AmirFT: I thought you have already created a parser for your json. What i mean to say by the code is that if you are storing your whole response , which i suppose is an array, in data. Then data[section] will give you the object at particular section(index). that object has key value pairs . So basically `dataAtSection` is your keyvalue  pair `let contactsArray = dataAtSection["contacts"] 
return contactsArray.count
`